# PHP.ini Timezone equal to host OS timezone

Tags: php, timezone

Is there a way to configure in `php.ini` the timezone to be set equal to the host operating system - OS - timezone, so that every time PHP is started it looks at the host OS and automatically adjust its timezone ?

Something like:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = [Timezone configured on the operational system]
```

I´m currently using Linux as the host OS.

Comment: host SO timezone or host OS timezone?

Comment: So... is there something about the error message PHP gives of `"It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings"` that you don't understand?  https://chrisjean.com/php-5-3-and-system-timezone-settings/

Comment: Until 5.3 it used the system time, of you just leave it empty (and gives you NOTICE on that). Since 5.4 you need to define timezone explicitly.